# Unexplainable identifier in DOMException

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, material-design

I am trying to use Google's Material desingn.

I have a component below whose path is epimss_design/lib/component/menu/main-menu-form.html; epimss_design is the app's name.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_drawer_panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_icon_button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">

  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/paper_elements/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">

  <polymer-element name="main-menu-form">

      <style>
        :host {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #core_drawer_panel {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 10px;
        }

        #section {
          box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 3px;
          background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
        }

        #section1 {
          height: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
        }

        #core_toolbar {
          right: 0px;
          color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          background-color: rgb(79, 125, 201);
        }


    </style>

    <template>
      <core-drawer-panel id="core_drawer_panel">
        <section id="section" drawer></section>
        <section id="section1" main>
          <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
            <core-icon-button icon="menu" id="core_icon_button"></core-icon-button>
            <div id="div" flex>Toolbar</div>
          </core-toolbar>
        </section>
      </core-drawer-panel>

    </template>

    <script type="application/dart">

      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
      import 'dart:html';

      //import 'package:epimss_polymer/.dart';


      @CustomTag( 'main-menu-form' )
      class MainMenuForm extends PolymerElement
      {

        MainMenuForm.created() : super.created();

        void menuAction()
        {
          print ( 'Menu tapped' );
        }
      }

    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

The entry_point epimss_design.html is as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>ePIMSS</title>
      <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
           not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
      <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

      <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

      <link rel='import' href='packages/epimss_design/component/menu/main-menu-form.html'>

      <script type="application/dart">
        export 'package:polymer/init.dart';

      </script>

      <!-- <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script> -->


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="epimss_design.css">
    </head>

    <body unresolved>
      <main-menu-form></main-menu-form>


  </body>
  </html>
```

When I run the application I am consistently getting the following error

```
     Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element':    
     '#packages/epimss_design/component/menu/menu' is not a valid selector. (http://127.0.0.1:8080/epimss_design.html:1509)
Exception caught during observer callback: Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#packages/epimss_design/component/menu/menu' is not a valid selector.
    at Error (native)
    at core-iconset-svg.Polymer.iconById (http://127.0.0.1:8080/epimss_design.html:1509:59)
    at core-iconset-svg.Polymer.cloneIcon (http://127.0.0.1:8080/epimss_design.html:1513:25)
    at core-iconset-svg.Polymer.applyIcon (http://127.0.0.1:8080/epimss_design.html:1557:24)
    at core-icon.Polymer.updateIcon (http://127.0.0.1:8080/epimss_design.html:1461:17)
    at core-icon.g.invokeMethod (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:13320)
    at core-icon.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:11606)
    at Object.Observer.report_ (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/web_components/platform.js:12:12616)
    at Object.createObject.check_ (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/web_components/platform.js:12:18105)
    at c (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/web_components/platform.js:12:5467) (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/web_components/platform.js:12)
```

The last menu in the exception is meaningless to me. I have no clue where it is coming from. I expect the last menu to be main-menu-form, the name of the component. I hope it makes sense to someone.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please format the error message as code so its obvious what words actually are part of the error message (I hope its the whole error message without any changes).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by this bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19770

see also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/Jbiml0hFH40

The transformer seems to have an error in how it handles the `src` attribute of the `img` element (in `core-icon`)

**UPDATE**
These attributes need special treatment because they are evaluated by the browser before Polymer has a chance to evaluate the binding. The solution provided by Polymer is to bind to the attributes `_src` and `_img` instead.

Comment: Here is a long discussion about a similar error https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/35